# ¿Cómo crear objetos o Enumerables de forma dinámica?

Tags: c#, wcf

Mi modelos es el siguiente:

```
public class ResponseMessage
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable Data { get; set;}
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es retorna una respuesta al cliente estoy usando `WCF` en `c#`, entonces retorno un objecto como el siguiente:

```
{
data:[
//aqui van datos aleatorios 
//ya sea solo un conjunto de datos o multiples objectos con sus respectivos datos
],
message: "operación Exitosa",
result: "1"
}
```

Actualmente en mi función tengo lo siguiente

```
    ResponseMessage response = new ResponseMessage();
                dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
                  response.Data = data.data = "-2";        
                  response.Result = _result["result"].ToString();
                  response.Message = _result["message"].ToString();
                       return response;
```

esto me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
{
    "Data": [
        "-",
        "2"
    ],
    "Message": "Ya existe el usuario",
    "Result": "-1"
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no he podido resolverlo. el resultado que busco en data puede ser un objecto o una lista, la estructura que busco es:

```
{
    "Data": {
     data: "-2"
    },
    "Message": "Ya existe el usuario",
    "Result": "-1"
}
```

Comment: creo que lo que necesitas es pasarlo a Json

Comment: no entendi la ultima parte `la estructur que busco dentro de data es data: "-2", y no que me de los valores separados`, que significa ?

Comment: lo edite para un mejor entendimiento, espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: puedes agregar el encabezado de  tu metodo? cual es el formato que quieres regresar (content type)?

Comment: La popiedad `Data` es `IEnumerable ` con lo cual es una lista, que la respuesta sea un objeto implica que debas cambiar el tipo de datos

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer que Data sea un array deberias pasarle un array al response.

```
response.Data = data.data = new List<object> { "-2" };
```

Con esto devolverias  ... "data" : [ "-2" ] ...

Si quieres la propiedad dinamica, cambiala a object.

```
public class ResponseMessage
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set;}
}



response.Data = data.data = new { data = "-2" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Para soportar dos tipos de datos podrias usar

[Tipos conocidos de contratos de datos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types)

Entonces creas clases que hereden

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ResponseMessageList))]
[KnownType(typeof(ResponseMessageInfo))]
public class ResponseMessage
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseMessageList : ResponseMessage
{
    public IEnumerable Data { get; set;}
}


public class ResponseMessageInfo : ResponseMessage
{
    public string Data { get; set;}
}
```

O quizas especificar la herencia en la propiedad

```
[DataContract]
public class Data { }

[DataContract(Name = "DataList")]
public class DataList : Data 
{
    public List<string> Data { get; set;}
}

[DataContract(Name = "DataString")]
public class DataString : Data 
{ 
    public string Data { get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DataList))]
[KnownType(typeof(DataString))]
public class ResponseMessage
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set;}
}
```

La idea es que puedas con a herencia asignar un `List<string>` o un `string` segun necesites

Comment: Leandro entonces si uso ese modelo con herencia, no tendre problemas para retornar la estructura que busco conseguir ? es que la que indico en el problema, bueno la probare vere si me sale el resultado correcto. gracias

Comment: Esto no es magico, quizas requiera alguna adaptacion, pero con herencia puedes redefinir en la implementacion de las clases como se devuelve una propiedad

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo de como generar  esa parte yo trato de hacer algo como,
response.data = new List<DataString>{new {data = "-2"}}; pero creo no es la forma correcta

Comment: pero queres retornar una lista de string o es solo un string ? porque quizas no necesites de la herencia

Comment: quiero retornar la estructura que menciona arriba en el ejemplo, aveces solo sera un dato, y aveces sera un objeco mas completo como
{
data:[
data: "-2",
datos:[
nombre: "benja",
ciudad: "california"
]
]
}